# Different New users Google analytics and Developer console

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have setup my app analytics with google analytics, there the total new users it showing 105,500 and in developer console it showing 38,500. why is there so much difference?

Comment: bcoz developer console is updated every 24-48 hours, and analytics is almost realtime
thus this gap

Answer (score 0):

I would say the real reason is that the develop console only shows apps obtained through legit means ie. the play store. If a user installs the apk directly (and unfortunately your app will be available for free via a quick google search) then analytics will pick it up but the dev console wont. I'd advise putting in some sort of licensing check. here is a good starter for 10: [Google Play Licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html)